# TABLEAU - How to use aggregated values within STR function

Tags: string, tableau-api

My data in Tableau is in pivot format.
Region/City/Neighboor/Street columns, metric column with different numerical metrics and a column "Measure" that stores the given metric's value.

I want to create a calculated field and combine the SUM(Measure) if metric=A with some text

I tried creating a calculated filed as "Some Text" + STR(SUM(IF metric='A' THEN Measure END))
I receive an error "Cannot mix Aggregate and Non Aggregate Arguments" Is there any way to mitigate this issue ?

Thank you

Comment: Is your Measure already and aggregate? Because I can do this with Superstore data without an error: "Some Text " + str(sum(if [Category]='Technology' then [Sales] end))

Answer (score 0):

Already the measure is aggerated try using this : "Some text" + str(if ATTR([Region])='Europe' then Measure_value end)